# How to have buttons in fixed position inside of <div> class?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set all my buttons to be fixed inside of `<div>`. I want the buttons to line up with the image on the left, and under the texts. I tried using a fixed, absolute position but then I had to create CSS for each button, which I found inefficient. Also, I found that one button is formatting weirdly, although they all have the same CSS. Or when I try to minimize the windows, the buttons start going out of places.. which I don't find the reasons to. Below is my code:

```css
.secondContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul {
  padding: 10px;
}

li {
  text-align: left;
}

li.title {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

li.author {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 12px;
}

li.isbn {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 12px;
}

li.price {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.flexItem {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 10px;
  flex: 1;
}

.flexItem img {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.button {
  color: white;
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.buttonCart {
  width: 120px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #dd1d5e;
}

.buttonCart:hover {
  background-color: #dd1d5e;
  color: white;
}

.buttonOnline {
  width: 120px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #dd1d5e;
}

.buttonOnline:hover {
  background-color: #dd1d5e;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="secondContainer">

  <div class="flexItem">
    <img src="images/books/holiday/thanksgiving_recipes.png" alt="Thanksgiving Recipes" class="image">
    <div class="text">
      <ul>
        <li class="title"> Thanksgiving Recipes </li>
        <li class="author"> Hannie P Scott </li>
        <li class="isbn"> ISBN123123412 </li>
        <li class="price"> $2.92 </li>
      </ul>
      <button class="button buttonCart">Add to Cart</button>
      <button class="button buttonOnline">Read Now</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flexItem">
    <img src="images/books/holiday/giving_thanks.png" alt="Thanksgiving Recipes" class="image">
    <div class="text">
      <ul>
        <li class="title"> Giving Thanks </li>
        <li class="author"> Kathleen Curtin </li>
        <li class="isbn"> ISBN123123412 </li>
        <li class="price"> $1.45 </li>
      </ul>
      <button class="button buttonCart">Add to Cart</button>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@sarah, you can try this for your css:

```
 display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul {
  /*padding: 10px;*/
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  text-align: left;
}

li.title {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

li.author {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 12px;
}

li.isbn {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 12px;
}

li.price {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.flexItem {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 10px;
  flex: 1;
}

.flexItem img {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.button {
  color: white;
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

.buttonCart {
  width: 120px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #dd1d5e;
}

 .buttonCart:hover {
  background-color: #dd1d5e;
  color: white;
 }

.buttonOnline {
  width: 120px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #dd1d5e;
}

 .buttonOnline:hover {
  background-color: #dd1d5e;
  color: white;
}
.text{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

I just added flex property to your "text" class. And it seem standart now.

Answer (score 1):

Just put two buttons in a div and add class to the div and in that case there is no need for position absolute like this :

```
<div class="marginLeft">
 <button> Button 1 </button>
 <button> Button 2 </button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.marginLeft {
  /* If the div doesn't look right uncomment the next line */
  /* display:inline; */
  margin-left:10px
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `flex-direction:column;` to `.flexItem` class and delete the 2 properties for selector `.flexItem img`

Then add desired width to `img` elements like this:

```
img {
width:200px; /* for example */
}
```

Codepen here to play with:

https://codepen.io/larrytherabbit/pen/PozPaMG

Scrnshot: https://prnt.sc/uyplra

If you want to align all items (img, text, buttons) to the left in the `.flexItem` container change`align-items` to `flex-start` instead of `center`.

Comment: screenshot with flex-start for the `flexItem` class https://prnt.sc/uypn68

Answer (score 1):

you don't need trouble just button class remove the front of **dot .**  and add into button class **margin-left : 10px**
you see below the css code I commented it

```css
.secondContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul {
  padding: 10px;
}

li {
  text-align: left;
}

li.title {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

li.author {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 12px;
}

li.isbn {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 12px;
}

li.price {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.flexItem {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 10px;
  flex: 1;
}

.flexItem img {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
//like this 
button {
  color: white;
  padding: 2px;
  margin-left : 10px
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.buttonCart {
  width: 120px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #dd1d5e;
}

.buttonCart:hover {
  background-color: #dd1d5e;
  color: white;
}

.buttonOnline {
  width: 120px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #dd1d5e;
}

.buttonOnline:hover {
  background-color: #dd1d5e;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="secondContainer">

  <div class="flexItem">
    <img src="images/books/holiday/thanksgiving_recipes.png" alt="Thanksgiving Recipes" class="image">
    <div class="text">
      <ul>
        <li class="title"> Thanksgiving Recipes </li>
        <li class="author"> Hannie P Scott </li>
        <li class="isbn"> ISBN123123412 </li>
        <li class="price"> $2.92 </li>
      </ul>
      <button class="button buttonCart">Add to Cart</button>
      <button class="button buttonOnline">Read Now</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flexItem">
    <img src="images/books/holiday/giving_thanks.png" alt="Thanksgiving Recipes" class="image">
    <div class="text">
      <ul>
        <li class="title"> Giving Thanks </li>
        <li class="author"> Kathleen Curtin </li>
        <li class="isbn"> ISBN123123412 </li>
        <li class="price"> $1.45 </li>
      </ul>
      <button class="button buttonCart">Add to Cart</button>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the right side into a flex container. (Background colors, width and height are not necessary of course.)

```css
.right-side{
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background:red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  .text-wrapper{
    background: yellow;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
  }
  
  .button-wrapper{
    flex: 0 0;
  }
```

```html
<div class="right-side">
  <div class="text-wrapper">
      <ul>
          <li class="title"> Thanksgiving Recipes </li>
          <li class="author"> Hannie P Scott </li>
          <li class="isbn"> ISBN123123412 </li>
          <li class="price"> $2.92 </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="button-wrapper">
      <button class="button buttonCart">Add to Cart</button>
      <button class="button buttonOnline">Read Now</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your answer. However, I don't see the img element there? Also that doesn't re-use OP CSS code which is mostly good already...